# Using flatMap in RestManager with generic function not working

Tags: swift, combine

I am new to Combine, so I wanted to create class *RestManager* for networking with generic
*fetchData* function. Function is returning *AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never>* where *ErrorType* is enum with *.noInternetConnection, .empty and .general* cases.

I tried to use *URLSession* with *dataTaskPublisher* and *flatMap*

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never> {
    URLSession
        .shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .flatMap { (data, response) -> AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never> in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                if let data = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data){
                    return Just(data).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                if let error = error as? URLError {
                    switch error.code {
                    case .notConnectedToInternet, .networkConnectionLost, .timedOut:
                        return Fail(ErrorType.noInternetConnection).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    case .cannotDecodeRawData, .cannotDecodeContentData:
                        return Fail(ErrorType.empty).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    default:
                        return Fail(ErrorType.general).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But I am getting

*Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never>.Output, URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure>' (aka 'AnyPublisher<AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never>.Output, URLError>') to return type 'AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never>'* error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several major flows in your implementation.

Firstly, you shouldn't be using `Result` as the `Output` type of the `Publisher` and `Never` as its `Failure` type. You should be using `T` as the `Output` and `ErrorType` as `Failure`.

Second, you need `tryMap` and `mapError`, not `flatMap`.

Lastly, you are handling the result of `dataTaskPublisher` completely wrong. When `dataTaskPublisher` fails, it emits an error, so you need to handle that in `mapError`. When it succeeds, it emits its result as `data`, so you need to be decoding that, not `response`.

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, ErrorType> {
    URLSession
        .shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap { data, _ in
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        }
        .mapError { error -> ErrorType in
            switch error {
            case let urlError as URLError:
                switch urlError.code {
                case .notConnectedToInternet, .networkConnectionLost, .timedOut:
                    return .noInternetConnection
                case .cannotDecodeRawData, .cannotDecodeContentData:
                    return .empty
                default:
                    return .general
                }
            default:
                return .general
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```